# Create Delete/Edit buttons for muliple records from linq using hidden value?

Tags: c#, linq, edit, delete-row

Aspx form:

```
<asp:Table ID="viewV" runat="server">
  <asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Type</asp:TableHeaderCell>
  </asp:TableRow>       
</asp:Table>
```

Code below:

```
vRepository getV = new vRepository();

var viewAllV = getV.GetV();

foreach (tblV singleV in viewAllV)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    // Create four new cells for each row within the database

    TableCell vName = new TableCell();
    TableCell vType = new TableCell();

    // Attached values to each of these cells

    vName.Text = singleV.vName;
    vType.Text = singleV.tblVType.vName;

    // Add the cells to the table

    tr.Cells.Add(vName);
    tr.Cells.Add(vType);

    // Add the row to the table

    viewV.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

I am currently populating a asp:table using LINQ, this is working fine.

```
public IQueryable<tblV> GetV()
{
    return (from getAllV in dc.tblV
            where getAllV.deleted != 1
            orderby getAllV.vName
            select getAllV).DefaultIfEmpty();
}
```

**I have tried the GridView/ListView/DetailsView but can’t seem to access the GetV, I can only access the actual table.**

I want to add a edit/delete button to the end of every row, so that the user can select the row they wish to edit/delete.

Once the user has selected either the edit/delete button, this should then access a different view (one for edit, one for add - within the same aspx file).

For example:

```
Name    Type

Example 1   Type 1  Edit Button Delete Button

Example 2   Type 1  Edit Button Delete Button
```

I want to be able to select the Edit Button for ‘Example 1’. This should then:

1. Take me to the ‘edit view’,
2. Auto populate the two text fields with the correct information,
3. Update row (within database) with new information using unique ID(PK).

How came I produce multiple edit/delete buttons which somehow hold the unique ID for that row?

I thought it would be something like this:

```cs
TableCell vEdit = new TableCell();
vEdit.Button = singleV.vID;
tr.Cells.Add(vEdit);
```

Comment: any particular reason you don't want to use a gridview or a listview?  They would really simplify this a lot for you.

Comment: I want to be able to learn how to 'hard code' this rather than drag and drop as if something goes wrong I want understand the code. Plus I need the Edit/Delete button to go to another view rather than create an inline 'edit' mode.

Comment: You should probably do this the 'right' way instead of the 'hard way'. There will be plenty of time to mess with complicated bits elsewhere. Try GridView/DetailView for an editing mode that is not inline. At worst, at lease use a Repeater instead of a Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to "hard-code" it, use ASP.NET MVC. Otherwise, you really should use some sort of databound control.

That said, if you insist on this approach you can probably do something like this:

```
Button editButton = new Button();
editButton.Text = "Edit";
editButton.CommandArgument = singleV.vID.ToString();
editButton.CommandName = "Edit";
editButton.OnCommand += new CommandEventHandler(EditButton_Command);

TableCell vEdit = new TableCell();
vEdit.Controls.Add(editButton);

tr.Cells.Add(vEdit);
```

Then from your event handler's [CommandEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.aspx) you can retrieve the argument and change your view accordingly.

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m not making myself clear, I do want the best solution, however I am struggling to adapt the databound controls to suit my requirements. I need to access the GetV (currently located within a Class). Within GetV I am using LINQ. When I try to attach a datasource it only allows me to access the actual table and not the GetV. I also want the edit/delete buttons to go to another view whilst still containing the unquie ID. If the views are the best solutions can anyone recommend any documentation which provide a step by step guide,  regarding my requirements?